# Site Crashing IE8 - forcing it into compatibility mode

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, ie8-compatibility-mode

Site: http://www.mccaonline.com

I have recently been working on the site MCCAOnline.com and are running into several issues specifically in Internet Explorer 8.  When I try to load the site in IE8, it crashes and reverts to compatibility mode.  I looked around extensively online and it seems like some people had run into issues with the respond-ie.js file.  I moved this to the bottom of the page to no avail.

In compatibility mode, the following issues occur:

1)  The footer elements stack on top of each other
2)  The navigation drop down does not work

Additionally, there is a white margin on the right hand side of the page.  I am not sure what is causing this or whether it's related to the IE8 bug, because it's appearing in all browsers.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

best,
clint

Answer (score 0):

I use IE8 on XP SP3 with full update, and it's not crash. 
Do you update the newest version of IE8?

Comment: I should clarify - it's causing it to load in compatibility mode, which is causing the footer elements to stack and disabling the dropdown navigation.  When you load it in your browser, does the dropdown menu work?  Does the site load in compatibility mode?